# Find which grid cells contain a point

Tags: r, overlay, vector-grid

I have a dataframe with x,y coordinates. I've sampled 10 x,y coordinates from my dataframe:

```
y <-c(24.637032,21.569813,21.687,19.677183,24.72438,21.433136,24.637032,22.21065,21.443762,25.273882)

x <-c(-156.02597,-112.00287,-112.00287,-105.27803,-159.47324,-157.858,-156.026,-109.68626,-112.12681,-112.15393)
```

I've converted these points to a `SpatialPoints` objects:

```
library(sp)
myPoints <- data.frame(x,y)
coordinates(myPoints) <- c('x', 'y')
proj4string(myPoints) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84")
```

I've used these points to make a `SpatialGrid`object:

```
bb <- bbox(myPoints)
myPointsGrid <- GridTopology(cellcentre.offset =  bb[, 1] + (cs/2), cellsize = c(1, 1), cells.dim = ceiling(diff(t(bb))/cs))
myPointsGrid <- SpatialGrid(myPointsGrid, proj4string = "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84")
```

I need two things 1. find which grid cells contain a point 2. Find the number of points in each grid cell. I tried...

```
over(myPointsGrid, myPoints)
```

...but this has thrown an error. How can I complete this task?

Comment: What kind of error do you get? And waht is 'cs' exactly? Cause when I run your code I get an error there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your code is correct (I have given the value 1 for the cs variable), the error it gives is:

```
Error in function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘over’ for signature ‘"SpatialGrid", "SpatialPoints"’
```

According to the help file, this is what the function is waiting as input:

```
x: geometry (locations) of the queries
y: layer from which the geometries or attributes are queried
```

It means that you are giving the wrong order of inputs, first is the point location followed by the layer. This is what you want:

```
> over(myPoints,myPointsGrid)
  [1]  59 268 213 330   1 222  59 215 268  48
```

*with cs=1*